# Why does authentication fail when using IBM Rational's sample Java code to connect to a ClearCase server?

Tags: java, clearcase

I am running the sample code provided in this link : [teamapi_cc_full_sample.htm](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_7.1.1/com.ibm.rational.team_api_cc_tut.doc/topics/teamapi_cc_full_sample.htm), however it is never able to successfully login and continuously retries.

I know the server URL I pass in is correct because if I enter into my browser I get the following message from the CM Server :

```
{http://stp.rational.ibm.com/ws/teamservice}Team

Hi there, this is a Web service!
```

The username and password combination I use are exactly the same as what I use when logging into ClearQuest or the ClearCase solaris server.

Am I missing something?

if I do

```
cleartool -version
```

I get

```
Clearcase Version 8.0.1.00
```

Comment: What version of the CM server are you using on your solaris server? Can you check the header of the returned frames in a Firefox Network debug session (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor)?

Comment: I am using Clearcase version 8.0.1.00.  I will try to look at the returned frames, but what exactly am I looking for?